# Android Admob Error Code 1 The ad has already been shown

Tags: android, admob, adsense

I am encountering a new kind of error with Admob.

The ad is being shown but im getting this error when `onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent` is being triggered .

```
{ "Code": 1, "Message": "The ad has already been shown.", "Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads", "Cause": "null" }
```

does anyone know the reason behind this code? and how am I supposed to handle it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure to dispose your ad after showing it, like so:

```
interstitialAd.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
  onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (ad) {
    print('onAdDismissedFullScreenContent');
    ad.dispose();
  },
  onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (ad, error) {
    print('onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: $error');
  },
  onAdShowedFullScreenContent: (ad) {
    print('onAdShowedFullScreenContent');
  },
);
interstitialAd.show();
```

In addition, don't forget to initialize it again before next time your show it.

Comment: I've been showing the ad once, and this error is retrieved from the 1st try. I ended up removing the interstitial ads since google have applied Ad Limit to my account .

Comment: @Anthony, first, you need to add your device to the test device list in order to prevent your account from beeing

Comment: @Anthony, First you need to add your DeviceId into the "Test device list" in order to prevent google from blocking you ads.
And also, please make sure you haven't called InterstitialAd.load() twice.
If you'll show us your code, maybe it will be easier.

Comment: i delete the code actually, no more interstitial, thank you for your help. I will follow you if i need another help later